# Поочередное выполнение задач с Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я создал небольшой скрипт на промисах, который поочередно выполняет 2 функции, но мне не нравиться его структура. Мне не нравиться что промис ожидает решения не выполнения самой функции, а дополнительно рассчитанной величины для `setTimeout`. Мне так же не нравиться что для очередности действия я вложил промис в промис, так есть сначала я жду окончание удаления, потом окончание добавления, а не делаю все одним промисом, то есть выполнил удаление, then - выполнил добавление.

Вот пример проблемы с задержкой:

```
let p1 = new Promise(
   (resolve, reject) => {
        removeLine();            //рабочая функция, выполнение которой я ожидаю
        window.setTimeout(
            function() {
                resolve(thisPromiseCount); 
            }, getText()*speed); //<- ждем столько, сколько строк*скорость
    }
);
```

Я тут ибо я хочу узнать нет ли какого-либо другого решения этому? Могу ли я просто подождать выполнение функции, чего бы внутри нее не было и приступить к следующему этапу что бы вот не делать такие задержки в промисах? Явно ж должно быть решение. Хотя при этом хочется что бы вся структура не нарушилась (так есть если я добавлю какой либо скрипт часов, что бы он не заморозился в ожидании выполнения функции, придирчивый я сильно).

Прилагаю рабочий пример моего кода ниже для удобного анализа для решения вопроса. Благодарю за внимание!

```js
var el = $("#t");
var speed = 200;
var delay = 2000;
var N = 6;

function removeLine() {
 console.log("lines removed");
  el.empty();
}
function addLine(N) {
  for (i=0; i<=N; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("#"+i+" line generated");
        el.append("<p>Line #"+i+" is here!</p>");
      }, speed * i);
    })(i)
  }
}
function getText() {
 return $(el).find("p").length;
}

var promiseCount = 0;

function testPromise() {
    let thisPromiseCount = ++promiseCount;

    let p1 = new Promise(
       (resolve, reject) => {
            removeLine();
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    resolve(thisPromiseCount);
                }, getText()*speed);
        }
    );

    p1.then(
        function(val) {
            let p2 = new Promise(
            (resolve, reject) => {
              addLine(thisPromiseCount-1);
                window.setTimeout(
                  function() {
                    resolve(thisPromiseCount);
                  }, thisPromiseCount*speed + delay);
            });
            
            p2.then(
             function(val) {
                 if (val == N) return;
                 testPromise();
             }
            ).catch((reason) => {
              console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
            });
        }).catch((reason) => {
            console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
        });
}

setTimeout(testPromise, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t">Hello World!</div>
```